# Codeigniter %B4 how to validate/filter

Tags: codeigniter

I am having an issue where if a post variable has %B4 in it, it will be urldecoded into a char that cannot be saved into the database without an error. (Even if I access via $_POST).

What is the best way to validate a field so these chars. cannot be saved?

Comment: I'm assuming the error is coming from the db?! You could use `Form_validation` and `preg_match()` to prevent the submission from going any further.

Comment: It is indeed coming from the database. What type or validation would I use that would let all charters except for invalid url decoded chars

Comment: try using addslashes when saving in db and removeslashes when retriving

Answer (score -1):

I think that maybe prey_match can help you.

```
<?php
   $subject = "abcdef";
   $pattern = '/^def/';
   preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
   print_r($matches);
?>
```